# Fake the date in header when printing in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, printing

When printing a webpage to PDF in Google Chrome, the header includes the date of the print by default.

Is there any way this date info can be faked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by setting your computer's clock backwards. Or by editing the PDF file using one of the dozens of (free and paid) PDF authoring tools that are available.

There are ways to detect that a PDF file has been edited *after* creation – for example, there are actually a few more timestamps in a PDF file (not just on the page, but also in metadata) – but none of those would reveal whether it was simply "printed" with the clock showing the wrong date.

If there is a need to prove that the PDF was created *no later* than a specific date, then various "trusted timestamping" services could be used.

Comment: Is it possible to do this directly in Chrome without modifying system date & time?